# How can I Dynamically add (unknown type) controls to a form?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Hi i want to add controls to my form with a general method, something like this:

```
void addcontrol(Type quien)
{
    this.Controls.Add(new quien);            
}

private void btnNewControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addcontrol(typeof(Button));
}
```

is this possible?

Comment: Just beware that adding a control with only its default property values is never useful.  Sooner or later, you really *do* care what kind of control it is.

Comment: @nobugz: that is when the property grid enters the action!!!

Comment: Making your own designer, are you?  Grokking TypeConverter and PropertyDescriptor yet?  It's a wild ride.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a new instance from the type instance using [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx):

```
void AddControl(Type controlType)
{
    Control c = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(controlType);
    this.Controls.Add(c);
}
```

It would be better to make a generic version:

```
void AddControl<T>() where T : Control, new()
{
    this.Controls.Add(new T());
}
```

Comment: +1 for the generic version. This will work fine as long as OP does not care about any functionality other than what the Control base offers.

Answer (score 1):

This would certainly work

```
void addcontrol(Control ctl)
{
    this.Controls.Add(ctl);            
}

private void btnNewControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addcontrol(new Button());
}
```

Comment: this is good but WHAT IF you want to check if a contol of that type already exists BEEFORE creating a new one?

Comment: You are allowed to have multiple controls of the same type in a form.

Comment: yeah but it will use memory that can be used in many, many, awesome things.